# Running batch file from Task Manager in Windows 2008

Tags: batch-file, taskmanager

I created a bat file to run a SQL query and create a text file as output, only if the value of query is greater then 2 (below is the bat file)

---

```
@echo off
cls

sqlcmd -S PRDDSOLP01 -U OLAP -P PASSWORD -d sqlADM -i \OLAP\olap.sql -h-1 -o olap.txt

set /p value=< olap.txt

if '%value%'=='2' goto Result
goto endif

:Result

sqlcmd -S PRDDSOLP01 -U PRSOLAP -P PRSOLAPonOLAP -d sqlADM -i \OLAP\olap.sql -h-1 -o olap.txt

:endif
DEL "olap.txt"

exit
```

---

This is working without any problem when I run the bat file on the server through command prompt, but when I schedule this to run using Task Manager it is not working.

I used Admin account to create task and also the same admin account has full control to the folder as well as the bat file, but no luck. SQL query, bat file are all in the same folder.

Comment: This is a pretty good thread that should help you http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservermanager/thread/d47d116e-10b9-44f0-9a30-7406c86c2fbe/ You are definitely not the only person to run into this problem...